# ConfigObj 'un-nest' sections

Tags: python, python-2.7, configobj

I'm using ConfigObj 5.0.6 to hold many user-defined values, some of which are nested. I use a `local.ini` to supercede typical values. There is no front-end, so users edit the configs as needed. To make that easier and more intuitive, there are some values that belong at the 'root' level of the config object, but are more easily understood below a nested section of the `local.ini` file.

I'm using a `local.ini` to supercede defaults. The flow of the app suggests a config layout that would have non-nested values below nested values.

```
# un-nested
title = my_title

# nested
[section_1]
val_s1 = val

[section_2]
val_s2 = val

# nested, but I want to be un-nested
val_2 = val
```

This layout, as expected, puts `val_2` under `section_2`:

```
{
 'title': 'my_title',
 {'section_1': {'val_s1': 'val'}},
 {'section_2': {'val_s2': 'val'},
               {'val_2': 'val'}}
}
```

Is it possible to define `val_2` on a line  *below*  `section_2`, but access it under the 'main' section of the config object?

I would like to end up with a config object like this:

```
{
 'title': 'my_title',
 {'section_1': {'val_s1': 'val'}},
 {'section_2': {'val_s2': 'val'}},
 'val_2': 'val'
}
```

The order of the config dictionary isn't important, of course; what I'm interested in is being able to use nested sections, but from within the `.ini`, exit a section into its parent.

I haven't tested, but suspect nesting *everything* from the first line onward and then slicing the config object would work. I.e., write `local.ini` such that it creates:

```
{
 'main_level':
  {
   'title': 'my_title',
   {'section_1': {'val_s1': 'val'}},
   {'section_2': {'val_s2': 'val'}},
   'val_2': 'val'
  }
}
```

Then I could use `config = config['main_level']` when I first instantiate the config object, but I'm wondering if I'm just missing some easy, correct way that isn't a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#the-config-file-format), that is not possible:

> In the outer section, single values can only appear before any sub-section.

Comment: well that's a real buzzkill! Thanks for the quick responnse